# Why is www.google.com not reachable?

Tags: ubuntu, router, dns

I just set up a new machine on my home network running Ubuntu 10.04. For some strange reason I can't reach `www.google.com`. All other domains work fine, even googles sub-domains like `docs.google.com`. I have no idea what the problem is.

`curl http://www.google.com/`

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

`ping www.google.com`

```
ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Unknown host
```

`dig www.google.com`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 51258
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     54813   IN  CNAME   www.l.google.com.

;; Query time: 46 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.3.1#53(192.168.3.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 10 14:48:35 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

The `google.com` 301 redirect is reachable, while `www.google.com` is not.

Comment: curl is saying it cannot resolve, yet the system can, which suggests something is up with curl itself.  Does wget work?  Can you try `curl -vvvvvv www.google.com`

Comment: "`www.` blindness" is a disease brought on by too much use of WWW browsers that automatically affix what one types in an address bar with other stuff.  ☺  `www.google.com.` is not the same domain name as `google.com.`, and this question's title is a falsehood.

Comment: It's not a curl problem, Safari, Chrome and Firefox also can't display google.com or www.google.com.

Comment: @JdeBP My bad, the `google.com` redirect **is** reachable, `www.google.com` is not. Still in IMHO still no reason to down vote right away ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dig` returns incomplete results, here's what I get:

```
$ dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.2.1 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54679
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.         0       IN      CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.       263     IN      A       209.85.229.99
www.l.google.com.       263     IN      A       209.85.229.103
www.l.google.com.       263     IN      A       209.85.229.104
www.l.google.com.       263     IN      A       209.85.229.105
www.l.google.com.       263     IN      A       209.85.229.147

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
l.google.com.           33378   IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
l.google.com.           33378   IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
l.google.com.           33378   IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
l.google.com.           33378   IN      NS      ns2.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.         193146  IN      A       216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.         193146  IN      A       216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.         193463  IN      A       216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.         193146  IN      A       216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 147 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 10 16:23:30 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 268
```

In particular the answer obtained by your dig lacks the `A` records for `www.l.google.com.`

I would use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) or similar tool to see what DNS queries were sent where and what DNS replies were received. Compare results on working and non-working PCs.

Answer (score 0):

When you `dig`ed for an A record, your DNS server returned a CNAME with no extra records. This is quite strange and may indicate the server can't resolve www.l.google.com.

"google.com" worked because CNAME can't be used with the "@" record, so A records must be returned directly. Maybe the DNS server 192.168.3.1 is filtering out l.google.com domains. 
Check if `dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com` gives you A records. If so, you may want to change your DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problem with DNS resolution. Maybe some issue with ISP's DNS cache.
You can directly check using Google's DNS server "8.8.8.8" and check.

```
lab@x:~$ dig www.google.com @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> www.google.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30985
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     81660   IN  CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.   113 IN  A   74.125.236.84
www.l.google.com.   113 IN  A   74.125.236.80
www.l.google.com.   113 IN  A   74.125.236.81
www.l.google.com.   113 IN  A   74.125.236.82
www.l.google.com.   113 IN  A   74.125.236.83

;; Query time: 42 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 12 00:25:58 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 132

lab@x:~$
```

If this is working fine then you may change

```
lab@x:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

to use this DNS server and then try sending a curl request.